# VS 2012 Asp.net MVC changes not coming up when running website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

After upgrading to VS 2012 any changes I make in my javascript classes do not seem to take effect until after I flush the browsers cache and rerun. i.e. Make change to line of javascript, run the website by click f5, changes are not there.

This wasnt occurring previously in VS 2010, or even the VS 2012 RC. Would there be a setting that is caching this?

Thanks

Comment: This is great when it comes to deployment time, but when in development having to clear the browser cache everytime is painful.

Comment: If using FF hit ctrl+shift+r when the page loads. This forces FF to re-read everything. Other browsers have other key configurations to do the same thing.

Comment: I wouldnt think would need to do this everytime i make a javascript change at development time? Seems like a bit of an oversight or a property that has/hasnt been set

Comment: I tried some other solutions I googled and the the only one that appeared to work was forcing a 'real' refresh. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am seeing the same behaviour. I think it has something to do with the "Bundling". I can change script that occurs in a page and the changes are immediately reflected, but if I change script in a .js file included through a bundle, I see the symptoms you describe.